# How to create contexts in shoulda macros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, macros, shoulda

Asking this question again with smaller code sample:

```
  # this is a dummy shoulda macro that creates a context
  def self.macro_context
    context "macro" do
      yield
    end
  end

  # i am expecting this test to fail within the macro context
  context "some context" do
    macro_context do
      should "test" do
        fail
      end
    end
  end
```

So what I would expect is to see:

```
  1) Error:
  test: some context macro context should test. (TestClassName)
```

But I am getting only this:

So what I would expect is to see:

```
  1) Error:
  test: some context should test. (TestClassName)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Francisco for the code, to fix this you cannot just yield the block inside of your new context, you have to use shoulda's [merge_block](http://rdoc.info/rdoc/thoughtbot/shoulda/blob/272aad1c4d5897ff232ec9a75a73c85b0f64554a/Shoulda/Context.html#merge_block-instance_method) method. It then should look like this:

```
  def self.macro_context(&block)
    context "macro" do
      merge_block(&block)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I have something similar in my code. And I did it like this into `test/shoulda_macros/whatever_file.rb`

```
def self.should_require_login(actions = [:index], &block)
 if (actions.is_a? Symbol)
   actions = [actions]
 end
 context "without user" do
   actions.each do |action|
     should "redirect #{action.to_s} away" do
       get action
       assert_redirected_to login_path
     end
   end
 end
 if block_given?
   context "active user logged in" do
     setup do
       @user = Factory.create(:user)
       @user.register!
       @user.activate!
       login_as(@user)
     end

     merge_block(&block)
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: the only difference seems to be in merge_block call, I have not seen that before, what does it do?

Comment: As it name says, it will merge the block that you pass with the block in which you're calling `merge_block`. In your case it will merge the given block inside the `context "active user logged in" do ... end`